# html5: why is my progressbar represented in green when I ask it to be in red?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Good day,

I'm learning html and css. In order to better understand how progressbar works, I have created a small demo page with a couple of buttons and the progressbar.

As you can see in my CSS code below, I ask specifically the background of my progressbar to be displayed in red color. This works absolutely fine on Internet Explorer. On an android device however, the same progressbar is rendered in green? Do I need to assume that it is not possible to define the background color of my progressbar for android? Or did I simply miss something?

Thanks for your clarification and help.

my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Progress example   </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_progress.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Avancement de la tâche à effectuer :
  <progress id="avancement" value="50" max="100"></progress>
  <span id="pourcentage"></span>
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(-10);" value="-">
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(10);" value="+">
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(10);" value="UP">
  </p>
  <script>
  function avancement() {
  var ava = document.getElementById("avancement");
  var prc = document.getElementById("pourcentage");
  prc.innerHTML = ava.value + "%";
  }

  function modif(val) {
  var ava = document.getElementById("avancement");
  if((ava.value+val)<=ava.max && (ava.value+val)>0) {
  ava.value += val;
  }
  avancement();
  }

  avancement(); //Initialisation
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code :

```
.test{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

progress[value] {

    /*border-radius: 2px; */
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    color:red;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to reset the progress bars styles:

```
progress[value] {
   /* Reset the default appearance */
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

   /* leave defaults in for other browsers */
   background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
   color:red; 
}
```

Now it is reset you'll want to set the element how you want it.

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
   /*border-radius: 2px; */
   background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
   color:red; 
}
```

This should do it for chrome that you are having problems with. Please see more indepth information [here](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
progress[value] {
  /*border-radius: 2px; */
  background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  color: red;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Avancement de la tâche à effectuer :
  <progress id="avancement" value="50" max="100"></progress>
  <span id="pourcentage"></span>
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(-10);" value="-">
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(10);" value="+">
  <input type="button" class="test" onclick="modif(10);" value="UP">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but keep your previous declaration

```
progress[value] {
  color: red
}
```

as it is necessary for IE

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value{background-color:red}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: This was my first answer on SO, ever.
Funny how when I refreshed, there was already 3 answers.